# how datagridview column header select as like row header

Tags: c#, winforms

Can we select Column Header of Data Grid View As like the multiple Row Header selection In the Data Grid View

It is Possible ?
any Suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found this online:

> In designview, Set the grid's SelectionMode to **ColumnHeaderSelect**
>   and set the AllowUserToOrderColumnsProperty to True

does it help?

Comment: Thank you 
I try this one 
but It Set An Exception :
Column's SortMode cannot be set to Automatic while the DataGridView control's SelectionMode is set to ColumnHeaderSelect

Comment: so? it clearly tells you to change Column's SortMode to something else than Automatic. move you mind ;-)

Comment: Thank You Davide Piras  
I appreciate your help 
thanks a lot